# Is there a way to get a test coverage report for unit testing in Dart Language?

Tags: dart, code-coverage, dart-unittest

Is there a way to get any type of a test or code coverage report (text or graphical) of the unit testing of your Dart code?

Answer (score 3):

Work in progress:

some links:

- [Dart Misc - Code Coverage Tool?](https://groups.google.com/a/dartlang.org/forum/#!searchin/misc/coverage|sort%3adate/misc/1Y-VM_wLDkg/8Kguem6zb24J) (could be already available)
- [Add support for code coverage in the VM](https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=4904)
- [`dart --coverage_dir` is unable to open file](https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=16288)

**Another approach**

- [Profiling the Standalone Dart VM on Linux](https://code.google.com/p/dart/wiki/Profiling)

Answer (score 3):

The [Coverage](http://github.com/dart-lang/coverage) project provides tooling that leverages the VM Observatory. It works both against the VM and Dartium and supports both pretty-printed and LCOV format output.